# radio button using angular 2

Tags: angular, radio-button

```
    <div class="FttTransferApply">
     <div>
       <label>
        <input #female name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" (click)="gender=female.value"/>
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'input-controls',
    templateUrl: './components/input-controls/input-controls.html'
})
export class InputControls {
    gender:string;
}
```

radio buttons not displaying using angular2. I want to display radio buttons using Angular2

Comment: <div class="input-controls"> used

Comment: That's meant to be `<input-controls></input-controls>` based on your selector. So it's the name of the element and not the class.

Comment: import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'input-controls',
    templateUrl: './components/input-controls/input-controls.html'
})
export class InputControls {
    gender:string;
}

Comment: i mentioned above is ts file

Comment: Which part are you not understanding? `selector: 'input-controls'` means that to "use" this component you do `<input-controls></input-controls>` and not `<div class="input-controls">`

Comment: radio buttons didn't display in browser

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44081693/edit) your question to show the code where you are using this component. Also note how you are running/building your application. I.e is this using SystemJS or is it an `@angular/cli` project? If the latter, then you should just need `templateUrl: 'input-controls.html'` where the template is in the same location as the class definition. Even with SystemJS you can do `id: module.id` and skip the relative path. And I also believe there is a loader shim for SystemJS do remove the need for the `id` even.

Comment: in browser any error ?

Comment: And of course check for console errors. Bottom line is it's either your usage, or the relative path to template. Or both. But please actually edit your question with further information rather than posting in comments.